# Multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Tags: go, go-templates

I am new to go and have difficulty rendring templates.

Here is my functions that are to generate template:

base.html

```
//Render templates for the given name, template definition and data object
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, name string, template string, viewModel interface{}) {
    // Ensure the template exists in the map.
    tmpl, ok := templates[name]
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "The template does not exist.", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, template, viewModel)
    if err != nil {
    log.Printf("temlate error here")
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}


 func EditNote(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //var viewModel models.EditChnl
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    //ch := bson.M{"id": "Ale"}
    title := vars["title"]
    log.Printf("%v\n", title)
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
        defer session.Close()
        session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
        c := session.DB("tlgdb").C("chnls")
        log.Printf("title is %s \n", title)
        var result  []models.Chnl
        err = c.Find(bson.M{"title": "xxx"}).All(&result)
        log.Printf("%v\n", result)

        if err != nil {
          log.Printf("doc not found")
          log.Fatal(err)
          return
        }
    renderTemplate(w, "edit", "base", result)
}
```

And here are the templates:

```
{{define "base"}}
<html>
  <head>
    {{template "head" .}}
  </head>
  <body>

    {{template "body" .}}

  </body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

edit.thml

```
{{define "head"}}<title>Edit Note</title>{{end}}
{{define "body"}}
<h1>Edit Note</h1>
<form action="/chnls/update/{{.Title}}" method="post">
<p>Title:<br> <input type="text" value="{{.Title}}" name="title"></p>
<p>Description:<br> <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description">{{.Description}}</textarea> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
</form>
{{end}}
```

The objects to render are:

```
type Chnl struct {
    Id    bson.ObjectId `json:"id"  bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title       string
    Description string
    CreatedOn   time.Time
    Creator     string
    Visits  int
    Score       int
}
```

The object that I'm trying to render exists in mongodb and I can print it out in console:

```
[{ObjectIdHex("56cc4493bc54f4245cb4d36b") sometitle blabla 2016-02-23 12:37:55.972 +0100 CET blabla 0 0}]
```

However I get this error:

```
temlate error here
http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
```

I'm wondering what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that you pass a slice of `Chnl` to the template:

```
var result  []models.Chnl
// ...
renderTemplate(w, "edit", "base", result)
```

And inside `renderTemplate()` param value of `viewModel` will be `result`.

And in your templates you refer to fields of the dot like if it would be a `Chnl` value and not a slice of it: `{{.Title}}`. So the first attempt to resolve it will fail.

Logging the errors is useful, so change your logging to also print the actual error, not just a generic error:

```
log.Printf("Temlate error here: %v", err)
```

Which results in:

> 2016/02/24 14:57:09 Temlate error here: template: edit.html:4:30: executing "body" at <.Title>: can't evaluate field Title in type []main.Chnl

I think you just want to pass 1 `Chnl` value and not a slice of them. In `EditNote()`:

```
if len(result) > 0 {
    renderTemplate(w, "edit", "base", result[0])
}
```

Next, know that [`http.Error()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error) writes content to the response. This means you cannot write further header values to the response. Usually when you call `http.Error()` in your handler, you should return without doing anything with the response:

```
if !ok {
    http.Error(w, "The template does not exist.", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return // NOTE THIS RETURN
}
```

Similarly, after all your `http.Error()` call insert a `return`. You may do some cleanup, but response should not be touched after `http.Error()`.

Comment: Further, if `ExecuteTemplate` encounters an error when writing, it has already written the status code and response headers. `http.Error` can't change them. You can work around this by executing into a buffer first and then writing out to the response ([see here for a how-to](http://elithrar.github.io/article/approximating-html-template-inheritance/#error-handling))